# Spring data elasticsearch document count info using built in reactive client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My problem:

I am trying to get indices information:

```
IndexName
IndexCreationDate
IndexAlias
IndexDocumentCount
IndexSize
```

I am able to get some of that information via `GetIndexResponse` mentioned below. Which holds alias, mapping and setting objects. However none of them have `IndexDocumentCount` and `IndexSize`. How to get that info using `ReactiveElasticSearchClient`?

I know there is a curl call which holds everything I need, but I thought there are posibilities using spring boot elastic built in java objects?

```
{{elastic-search-url}}/_cat/indices?v
```

I am using:

```
ELK : 7.17
Spring boot: spring-data-elasticsearch 5.1.3
```

```
ReactiveElasticsearchIndicesClient indices = reactiveElasticsearchClient.indices();

Mono<GetIndexResponse> getIndexResponseMono = indices.get(new GetIndexRequest.Builder().index("*").build());
GetIndexResponse block = getIndexResponseMono.block();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ReactiveElasticsearchIndicesClient.stats(IndicesStatsRequest)` to get the information about index statistics.

btw, using Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.1 against Elasticsearch is not tested.

Comment: Which version you would recommend? Also seems spring boot cannot autowire ReactiveElasticsearchIndicesClient. Instead I used reactiveElasticsearchClient.indices().stats(). Thanks for answer. :)